# How do you articulate a vector for a waterfall falling towards the center of the earth?

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to envision and think of a vector that represents a waterfall falling towards the center of a sphere (earth) that's scaling down in size towards zero as it approaches the center, as such the waterfall never reaches the center.

Comment: How is this "representation" of the waterfall by the vector related to "reaching the center (or otherwise)"?

Comment: It was to help give a mind's eye visual of what's occurring. That something is scaling down in infinite scale as it moves towards the center of a sphere.